# Get the src value from the img tag

Tags: javascript, html

I wrote this code part in my JavaScript file to select all `img` tags in my `.html` file.

```
var imgs = document.getElementsByTagName('img');
```

How can I extract the `src` values of those tags to an array for future use?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just try like this

```
function img_find() {
    var imgs = document.getElementsByTagName("img");
    var imgSrcs = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < imgs.length; i++) {
        imgSrcs.push(imgs[i].src);
    }

    return imgSrcs;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Use src tag:

```
  var imgs = document.getElementsByTagName("img")[0].src;
```

or

```
  var imgs = document.getElementById("imgid").src;
```

Answer (score 1):

You may try like this:-

```
var img = document.getElementById('myImg');
var attr = img.getAttribute('src');
```

or try simply like this:-

```
var imgs = document.getElementById('your_image_id').getAttribute('src');
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Array.prototype.map.call(document.getElementsByTagName('img'), function(img) {
  return img.src;
});
```

This is what [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) is for.

You can also use an empty array:

```
[].map.call(document.getElementsByTagName('img'), function(img) {
  return img.src;
});
```

If needing more browser support or wanting to use a util lib,

```
jQuery.map(document.getElementsByTagName('img'), function(img){ return img.src; });
```

or just use jQuery the way it's supposed to be used (though the above would work with `_.map`, using underscore or lodash):

```
jQuery('img').map(function(){ return this.src; });
```