# How do I return an image source as a string?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to turn an image source into a string so I can run `substring()` on it. I used the following JavaScript to get the source:

```
function ShowQuizAnswers(quiz) {
    var QuizImage = document.getElementById(quiz);
    var ImageType = QuizImage.attributes.src;
    console.log(ImageType);
}
```

Of course, as I soon found out, this returned an object instead of a string. I tried running `.toString()` on the `ImageType` variable, but that didn't work. Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: To get a string your would need `QuizImage.attributes.src.value`, but you should just get it the way Pranav C Balan says instead.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7882356/javascript-get-img-src-and-set-as-variable

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19342690/get-the-src-value-from-the-img-tag

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10843322/getting-img-src-value-path-name

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [Element#getAttribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getAttribute) or directly get [`src`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/src) property from dom object.

```
function ShowQuizAnswers(quiz) {
    var QuizImage = document.getElementById(quiz);
    var ImageType = QuizImage.src;
    console.log(ImageType);
}
```

or

```
function ShowQuizAnswers(quiz) {
    var QuizImage = document.getElementById(quiz);
    var ImageType = QuizImage.getAttribute('src');
    console.log(ImageType);
}
```

---

**FYI :** The [`attributes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/attributes) is an array like structure([NamedNodeMap](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NamedNodeMap)). It actually helps to iterate over all attributes an element, but you can't access the attribute directly from it.

*From the MDN docs:*

> The **Element.attributes** property returns a live collection of all attribute nodes registered to the specified node. It is a [NamedNodeMap](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NamedNodeMap), not an Array, so it has no Array methods and the Attr nodes' indexes may differ among browsers. To be more specific, attributes is a key/value pair of strings that represents any information regarding that attribute.

Comment: That works, thanks. Is there any reason to favor one of these methods over the other?

Comment: @ChrisLallo You're probably looking for the `src` property and not the `src` attribute, although they will be identical if the attribute is an absolute url. If the attribute is a relative url the property will still be the full url, which is usually more useful.

Comment: @ChrisLallo : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/attributes

Answer (score 1):

Try:

`const imageURL = document.getElementById(quiz).src`